# Find a number/s around average that meet a specific property

Tags: statistics, average, median, python

Lets say I have a specific list of numbers (33 in this case):

```
deltas = [24.81, 25.94, 26.18, 26.36, 26.49, 26.63, 26.63, 26.53, 26.53, 26.57, 26.55, 25.67, 25.9, 26.12, 26.35, 26.23, 26.56, 26.37, 26.5, 26.53, 26.73, 26.88, 27.03, 27.12, 27.77, 28.06, 28.6, 29.03, 29.12, 29.44, 29.31, 29.52, 27.45]
```

where:

```
size = len(deltas) # 33
delta_sum = sum(deltas) # 891.51
average = np.average(deltas) # 27.015454545454549
median = np.median(deltas) # 26.559999999999999
```

now these `deltas` produce another list of cumulative values where each element is the current sum.

```
s = 0
cumulatives = []
for delta in deltas:
    s += delta
    cumulatives.append(s)

# cumulatives = [24.81, 50.75, 76.93, 103.29, 129.78, 156.41, 183.04, 209.57, 236.1, 262.67, 289.22, 314.89000000000004, 340.79, 366.91, 393.26000000000005, 419.49000000000007, 446.05000000000007, 472.4200000000001, 498.9200000000001, 525.45, 552.1800000000001, 579.0600000000001, 606.09, 633.21, 660.98, 689.04, 717.64, 746.67, 775.79, 805.23, 834.54, 864.06, 891.51]
```

I want to find out if/when there is a number `x` (or a range of numbers) where for every `s` from the list of `cumulatives`: `s` divided by `x` and rounded to the closest integer will be equal to the position of `s` in the list.

e.g. for the 3rd element from cumulatives: `76.93`

```
round(76.93/x) should produce 3.
```

If we take the `average` or `median` this will be true for the most of the values in `cumulatives`, but not for all of them!

For example, if we use the `average = 27.015454545454549`, its true for element 17: `round(446.05/average) == 17`, but not for element 18: `472.42/average ~= 17.487 ~= 17`

If we use the `median = 26.559999999999999`, its not true only for the last 2 elements (32 and 33).

```
32: 864.06/median ~= 32.53 ~= 33
33: 891.51/median ~= 33.567 ~= 34
```

I know there is such `x` which satisfies the criteria for all elements in `cumulatives`, such a number is any number in the range: `[26.613:26.933]` (found the range by brute-force).

I don't know if its by accident, but the average of average and median is inside this range: `(average+median)/2 ~= 26.787`.

```
all((n+1 == int(round(c/26.787)) for n, c in enumerate(cumulatives))) # True
```

Don't know if this will aways be the case? Is there a way to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

It will not always be the case. Consider the set $\{1,2,6\}$ (your "deltas"). Then your set of "cumulatives" is $\{1,3,9\}$. The mean of the deltas is $\mu=3$, the median is $m=2$. Let $z=\frac{\mu+m}{2}=5/2$. We have $9/z=18/5=3.6$, which is $4$ rounded to the nearest integer, not $3$. I think it works for your example because the gap between each delta is less than one or a little larger than one.

By the way, your deltas are not in order (for example, the last number in the last is not the largest).

Comment: The problem with {1,3,9} is that there is no such $\hat x$ where $int(round(\frac{x_i}{\hat x})) = i$ for every $x_i$ in the set. I want to find an algorithm which can say if such $\hat x$ exists for a given set or not *(and then find that $\hat x$ once I know it exists)*. My initial assumption was that using $\mu$ or $m$ will be sufficient, but the example from the question shows, that they are not and yet $\hat x$ exists for the set. PS. Yes the deltas are not in order, but they will aways be positive, which makes the list of `cumulatives` ordered.